# How do you select all rows in addition to a calculated one?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose  `Table A`  has 1000 attributes and one of them is  `date` . I want to select and group by  `last_day` . So if I write this:

```
 select A.*
 from db.A
 group by last_day(A.date)
```

it selects the date but not  `last_day(A.date)` . How would I do this?

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of your table (with only a few columns) and the expected output? How are you expecting the columns to be aggregated?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  A.lastDay, A.Date
FROM    TableA A
GROUP BY A.lastDay, A.Date;
```

With this query you select items from the table, and group by on 2 columns.

If you want to know how many items are in that group, you can use `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT  A.lastDay, A.Date, COUNT(*)
FROM    TableA A
GROUP BY A.lastDay, A.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
with tab1 as(
select 1 col1, 'vish1' col2, trunc(sysdate) as tdate from dual union all
select 2 col1, 'vish2' col2, trunc(sysdate)+1 as tdate from dual union all
select 3 col1, 'vish3' col2, trunc(sysdate) as tdate from dual union all
select 4 col1, 'vish4' col2, trunc(sysdate)+1 as tdate from dual union all
select 5 col1, 'vish5' col2, trunc(sysdate) as tdate from dual 
)
select col1,col2, tdate from (
select col1,col2, tdate, row_number() over (partition by tdate order by tdate desc ) as rn from tab1)
where rn=1
```

here first I have create then from inner query I am selection record based on group by date(partition) the I am assigning rownumber to each row, since they are group by date there will be row_number in each group start from I am selection first record from it; you need to user order by clause to handle this.

Comment: This does not even use `LAST_DAY()` or anything equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Example execute on Oracel Hr schema. 
The Oracle/PL SQL LAST_DAY function returns the last day of the month based on a date value but it don't remove the time.

```
select to_char(last_day(sysdate),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual;


select trunc(last_day(start_date)),count(1) from job_history
group by trunc(last_day(start_date));
```

query counts how many record was in one month and grouping it by last day of month.

```
select trunc(last_day(start_date)),count(1) from job_history
where start_date >= trunc(last_day(start_date)) 
and start_date < trunc(last_day(start_date)) + 1
group by trunc(last_day(start_date));
```

query counts how many record was in last day of month and grouping it by last day of month.